# Text entry out of order during slowness Windows Server 2003 terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, terminal-server

When the server is running slowly, anything I type in any text entry box comes in out of order. For example, `IPCONFIG` might become `IPFIGCON`.

Basically, our Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Terminal Server is getting incredibly slow at times even under 1-2 user load. The server is at less than 10% ram and CPU usage. I am thinking this is a hard disk bottleneck of some sort but I also am curious as to why I'm getting bottlenecks with only 2 users logged in not doing anything too intensive.

Has anyone seen anything similar? I am looking for people who have experienced a slowness problem causing out of sequence text input, and would like to hear about how they resolved the problem. Not really looking for a guide of how to use disk queue length performance counters, but all input is always appreciated :)

I always vote and accept when possible!

Comment: I've seen this. I've typed stuff and had it show up 10 seconds later.

Comment: Do you use this server for any other processes? Do you connect to it through the internet or locally?

Comment: the server is on a machine that also hosts VM's, we are thinking some of the other VM's might be causing this garbled input due to IO / disk usage as that is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Detailed performance information/counters may already be available depending on the hypervisor used (hint: it may help to identify the hypervisor).